# Is there a way to get the shrinkwrap constraint to move the target to the object rather than the reverse?

Tags: animation, rigging, physics, constraints

In the image below there's a cuboid that has a shrinkwrap constraint to a distorted cylinder. As I rotate the distorted cylinder in the x-axis, the cuboid moves up and down following the uneven surface of the cylinder.

What I want is to flip this over and have the distored cylinder move up and down as it rotates over the stationary cuboid. That is, I want the same shrinkwrap constraint to move the target instead of the object. Does this make sense? Is there another way to go about it?
[image: CAM and pin with shrinkwrap constraint]

Comment: Can’t you just have the shrinkwrap constraint on the other object - ie, shrinkwrap the distorted cylinder to the cuboid rather than the cuboid to the distorted cylinder.

Answer (score 1):

This probably won't be the most efficient answer, because I don't really understand what end result you are trying to achieve, but you can add something called a driver.

Drivers let you "drive" values based on other values. So you could have rotation of one object drive the global position (or any other value) of another.